# Googlechart widths and heights as VW instead of PX

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-visualization

I make a system that is full resizable. I use Googlechart for a chart.

Are there tricks for me to make the chart also resizable width VW instead of PX? (on page load is enough)

In the div of the chart I do for the fontsize:
`#chart { font-size: 1vw !important }`

Answer (score 0):

if you leave all size settings *out* of the chart options,

the chart will become responsive to the container -- `<div>`

then use css to size the container

keep in mind the chart must be redrawn after any changes to container size

Comment: Yes. I didn't ask my question right. The full layout uses `width` with `vw`. When I see the layout on a very big screen the layout is very huge. That is what I want. But Googlechart uses for everything `px`. So the chart is unreadable on a very big screen. Maybe I can fix this with `transform scale` in css/jquery?